# Как сделать строку из ассоциативного массива

Tags: php

У меня есть ассоциативный массив:

```
[
   'action'=>'index.php',
   'method'=>'POST'
]
```

Мне нужно , чтобы ключ и значение были в таком формате: `action=index.php method=POST`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже сказали, если ключи не изменяются, можно просто записать в строку, а, если массив произвольный, я бы предложил использовать обычный foreach

```
$data = [ 'action' = > 'index.php', 'method' => 'POST' ];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $str[] = $key . '=' . $value; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если исходные

```
$data = [ 'action' = > 'index.php', 'method' => 'POST' ];
```

всегда имеют такой формат, то есть два ключа - `action` и `method`, как ни странно, проще чего будет прсто взять и сформировать строку

```
$str = "action={$data['action]} method={$data['method']}"
```

Если речь идет про произвольный массив,  то можно поступить как-то так

```
$str = implode(' ', array_map(function($k,$v){ return "$k=$v"}, $data) );
```

либо можно воспользоваться функцией `http_build_query`, что, конечно,  не совсем по назначению:

```
$str = http_build_query($data, '', ' ');
```

---

дополнение по комменту

```
class TagBuilder {
    public static funtion print($tag, $attrs, $close = false){
        if($close) return "</$tag>";
        if(!$attrs)  return "<$tag>";

        $attr_str = implode(' ', array_map(function($a, $v){ 
                           return "$a = \"$v\"";
                      }, $attrs));

        return "<$tag $attr_str>";
    }
}

echo TagBuilder::print("a", ['href' => "google.com", 'style' => 'color:red;']);
echo "google" ;
echo TagBuilder::print("a", null, true);
```

Comment: А если передавать этот массив как значение метода класса?

Comment: @ИванИванов дак передавайте, кто мешает то.

Comment: Простите, не так выразился, если передать этот массив как значение метода класса, чтобы из этого массива сформировать строку и сделать как атрибуты тега

Comment: @ИванИванов дополнил ответ, что-то вроде такого вы спрашиваете? или о чем речь?

Comment: Да, это ,спасибо большое)